# DDL load failed while importing _device

Tags: jupyter-notebook

when I wanna open jupyter notebook on cmd with this commend : "jupyter notebook" i get an error that is : DLL load failed while importing _device
how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today and my python version is Python3.9 from anaconda, while my NumPy version is 1.22.3.

I had tried to reinstall ipython and ipykernel with

```
pip install --upgrade ipykernel
```

```
conda uninstall ipykernel
python -m pip install ipykernel
```

and `nb_conda`

```
conda install nb_conda
```

But it doesn't work well, then I noticed that while I imported NumPy, it gives two types of errors: `DDL load failed while importing _device` and `DDL load failed while importing XXX`

For example:

```
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "D:\anaconda\envs\sample1\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.22.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath
```

So I checked the version of them and found they are not compatible, and then I tried to install them from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) with version `numpy-1.22.4+mkl-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` (choose what fits your python version and system) rather than using `conda install` in Anaconda prompt, and after I reinstall Numpy 1.22.4, I can import NumPy and use Jupyter Notebook.